# How do I get the SQL statement causing one SPID to block another?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I am running SQL Server 2019 and when spid A blocks spid B, I need to know the SQL statement/operation that spid A is running. How would I do this? I have a basic query below to get what spids are blocking others, but now I want to know the SQL statement that is causing the block. This will help me figure out where there are problems in my database.

```
select 

    t.spid
    , t.[name]
    , t.hostname
    , t.[program_name]
    , 'Blocked By:' [Blocked By:]
    , t2.spid
    , t2.[name]
    , t2.hostname
    , t2.[program_name]
    
from 

    _Running_Processes t with(nolock)
    left join _Running_Processes t2 with(nolock) on t.[Blocking spid] = t2.spid 

where

    t.[Blocking spid] <> 0
    
order by 

    t.[Blocking spid] desc
```

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel just use [sp_whoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/downloads/) or [sp_BlitzWho](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/sp_blitzwho/)

Comment: You can also use [beta_lockinfo](http://www.sommarskog.se/sqlutil/beta_lockinfo.html).